# Workflow for leave

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I was creating a workflow for leave request.

I want to calculate no. of leave days excluding Saturday & Sunday.

**For ex.**

- **From date**- 26-07-2017
- **To date**- 30-07-2017
- **calculate no. of leave days:** 4days of leaves

but if any Saturday & Sunday comes in between this duration, it should be neglected.

I am new to this workflow and Sharepoint.I can't use any code.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify this calculated field equation for use in a workflow:

[Calculating Days Excluding Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964332/calculate-days-excluding-weekends-in-sharepoint2010)